# Fix a timestamp timezone in PHP

Tags: php, timestamp-with-timezone

**A UNIX timestamp is timezone agnostic as it is a number of seconds since a precise moment in the past: we don't discuss it here but are dealing with so-called timestamp**

I'm working with an API which has a bug: provided timestamps are not real UNIX timestamps but from CET timezone.

For instance for this timestamp `1484521200`

- true meaning is `2017-01-15T23:00:00+00:00`
- from the API POV: `2017-01-16T00:00:00+00:00`

So I'm considering the following code to "convert" the timestamp from CET to UTC:

```
date_default_timezone_set('CET');
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp_API);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date, $timezone);
$timestamp_UNIX = $date->getTimestamp();
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // 1484524800
```

But I don't like it as I mess with the default timezone: is there any better way to this?

The best would be to fix the API but it won't happen anytime soon.

Comment: All unix timestamps are in GMT-0, it doesn't matter where they come from or what your default timezone is set to in PHP.

Comment: I know that all Unix timestamp are in GMT-0 but this API claims using UNIX timestamp but is actually using a "CET timezoned timestamp"

Comment: @Brogan I've dealt with clients whose systems set an intentionally *incorrect* time to get UTC timestamps to show up in their timezone without adding timezone handling to the app. Stupid, but it definitely happens.